# Select n objects randomly with condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Post, with a column called vote, and it has a big number of posts

I want to select n posts randomly that have >=x votes. n is very small compared to the number of posts

What is the best way to do this? I've tried a couple of ways that seem to be very inefficient. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on MySQL, you could order all the posts that meet the greater than criteria randomly and select the top n.

The actual query would look like

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE votes >= x ORDER BY rand() LIMIT n
```

Haven't tested this, but something like this should work in Rails:

```
Post.all(:conditions => ["votes >= ?", x], :order => "rand()", :limit => n)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because there's no "votes" column in the posts table.

Comment: I posted a new question asking about how is this operation performed internally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171082/in-which-order-rails-does-the-db-queries